# Using insert query in python for postgresql

Tags: python, postgresql, python-2.7, python-3.x

I want to insert values to a database using python, but it's failed. This is my code:

```
 try:
     cur.execute("""INSERT INTO tb_distance (objek1, objek2, distance) VALUES ('%s','%s','%d')""", (data[i].jenis, data[k].jenis, distance))
     conn.commit()
 except:
     conn.rollback()
     print 'cannot insert into database'
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, I fixed my problem, I replace (,) to (%) before list of values. This is my code and run well:

```
cur.execute("""INSERT INTO tb_distance (objek1, objek2, distance) VALUES ('%s','%s','%f')""" % (data[i].jenis, data[k].jenis, distance))
```

Comment: +1 for answering your question. What you have done is correct but not secure, dont format values in python code use instead this: `cur.execute("""INSERT INTO tb_distance (objek1, objek2, distance) VALUES (%(objek1)s , %(objek2)s ,%(distance)s);""", {"objek1": data[i].jenis, "objek2": data[k].jenis, "distance": distance})`

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes around the placeholders (`'%s'` -> `%s`, `'%d'` -> `%d`):

```
cur.execute(
    "INSERT INTO tb_distance (objek1, objek2, distance) VALUES (%s, %s, %d)",
    (data[i].jenis, data[k].jenis, distance)
)
```